# How to open a Bloomberg Session using different user credentials

Tags: .net, bloomberg

How do I open a session without using the "Trusted Connection" of a windows user?
We have got a terminal which could be accessed by more than one user. To prevent users from using the Bloomberginterface you need to enter your own username and PW right into Bloomberg.

If I use the source from the API below... the Session will fail on this machine. If I run it from a machine with Windows authentication which matches the Bloomberg Login it works.

```
Dim serverHost As String = "localhost"
Dim serverPort As Integer = 8194
' set sesson options
d_sessionOptions = New SessionOptions()
d_sessionOptions.ServerHost = serverHost
d_sessionOptions.ServerPort = serverPort
```

What Do I need to do for the user credentials like username and PW?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is... you can't.

A Bloomberg Terminal licence, which includes use of the desktop API, is limited to a single machine - i.e. the machine on which the Bloomberg Terminal is installed and running. (Actually, the API relies on some programs besides the Terminal to be running, but that the user was recently logged into the Terminal and has not logged in elsewhere.)

If you require access to the Bloomberg API on other desks, you will have to get a Bloomberg Terminal licence for each desk.